# Remove js file by template or add condition in info file

Tags: theming, .info

I work on drupal 7, I added all js by info file, work well in whole site. But we want to remove or not load of a specific js in a specific content type page.

I try by template.php of following code

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']->type) && !empty($vars['node']->type) && ($vars['node']->type == 'my_content_type')) {
    $js_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . "/js/xyz.js";
      unset($vars[$js_path]);
  }
}
```

but load  xyz.js. How to remove of this js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_js_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7)

> Perform necessary alterations to the JavaScript before it is presented on the page.
>
> Parameters
>
> $javascript: An array of all JavaScript being presented on the page.

Then you should be able to use [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to load the node type and unset the js file in the $javascript array.

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter($javascript) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node->type == 'node_type) {
    unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this or checked syntax, let me know if it doesn't work and I will test.